# the meaning of "truncation" in image processing

Tags: image-processing

I'm studying a paper about image processing. In a part of this paper it is said that:

> We use Part Affinity Fields approach for pose detection in the wild.
>   It is robust to occlusion and **truncation**.

I cannot understand what it means from "truncation" here. I googled the term, but I didn't find anything useful. So what does "truncation" mean in image processing?

Comment: I don't know of a formal definition either, but in this context I interpret it as meaning when an object extends outside the field of view, and is therefore truncated by the boundaries of the image.

Comment: What @beaker said is right, in this context. But *truncation* is used in other contexts within image processing too. Truncation just means something is cut off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [dictionary definition of *truncation*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/truncation#English) is just right, also in this context:

> 1. The act of truncating or shortening.
> 2. (mathematics) The removal of the least significant digits from a decimal number.
> 3. (geometry) The replacement of a solid angle by a plane, or a similar operation in other dimensions.

In image processing, all three meanings can be intended, depending on context. In the context of the text in the question, meaning #1 is relevant. This definition seems a bit silly, but both *truncating* and *shortening* are links, which you are expected to follow. [*To truncate* is](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/truncate) (emphasis mine):

> 1. (transitive) **To shorten (something) by, or as if by, cutting part of it off.**
> 2. (mathematics, transitive) To shorten (a decimal number) by removing trailing (or leading) digits.
> 3. (geometry) To replace a corner by a plane (or to make a similar change to a crystal).

A part of an object in an image can be cut off by the image border: the object extends outside of the field of view.